# in 3 dependent box, 3rd box is not populating value using ajax and vbscript in asp classic

Tags: javascript, ajax, vbscript, asp-classic

I am populating 3(triple) dependent box using ajax and vbscript in asp classic page. 1st and 2nd boxes working ok. if i select STATE in 1st box then, in 2nd box CITY list is populating but when i select 2nd box (CITY), in 3rd box CENTER list is not populating.

my ajax script as below given:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getXMLHTTP() { 
    var xmlhttp=false;  
    try{
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e)    {       
        try{            
            xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e){
            try{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e1){
                xmlhttp=false;
            }
        }
    }

    return xmlhttp;
}

function getcity(stateId) {     

    var strURL="findcity1.asp?state="+stateId;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {                        

document.getElementById('citydiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                      
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }               
        }           
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }       
}
function getCenter(StateId,CityId) {        
    var strURL="findCenter.asp?state="+stateId+"&city="+cityId;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {                        
                     document.getElementById('centerdiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                       
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }               
        }           
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }

}
```

My code for populating STATES, CITY AND CENTER as below given

```
<%
dim Objrs_state, str_state, objCmd_state
Set objCmd_state = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set Objrs_state   = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
str_state = "SELECT ASId, ASName FROM State_Name ORDER BY ASName Asc"
With objCmd_state
.ActiveConnection = MM_connDUdirectory_STRING
.CommandText = str_state
.CommandType = adCmdText
end with 
Objrs_state.open objCmd_state, , 1, 2
%>
<select name="statid" onChange="getcity(this.value)">
<option>Select State</option>
<%while not Objrs_state.eof%>
<option value="<%=Objrs_state("ASId")%>"><%=Objrs_state("ASName")%></option>
<%Objrs_state.movenext
wend
Objrs_state.close
set Objrs_state = nothing
set objCmd_state = nothing%>
</select>

'populating CITY as below given

<span id="citydiv"><select name="city">
<option>Select City</option>
</select></span>

'populating CENTER as below given

<span id="centerdiv"><select name="center">
<option>Select Center</option>
</select></span>
```

FindCity.asp

```
Set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set Objrs   = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
str = "SELECT * FROM city_Name where ASId =? ORDER BY ACName Asc"
....
....
<select name="city" onChange="getcenter(stateID,this.value)">
<option>select city</option>
<% Do While Not Objrs.EOF %>
<option value="<%=objrs("ACId")%>"><%= Objrs("ACName")%></option>
<%
Objrs.MoveNext
Loop
%>
</select>
```

FindCenter.asp page

```
Set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set Objrs   = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
str = "SELECT * FROM Center_Detail where Center_state=? and Center_city=? ORDER BY Center_Name Asc"
....
....
<select name="center">
<option>select center</option>
<% Do While Not Objrs_center.EOF %>
<option value="<%=objrs_center("CnId")%>"><%= Objrs_center("Center_Name")%></option>
<%
Objrs_center.MoveNext
Loop
%>
</select>
```

1st and 2nd box populating and working fine but in 3rd box center list related to select city is not showing. Please help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: you are not specifying which function to call on `onchange` event of the city select

Comment: @SearchAndResQ  onchange event added in findcity.asp page. 1st and 2nd boxes are working fine..but 3rd box is not workin

Comment: @SearchAndResQ  please see ajax script

Comment: you have to add the value of the `statteid` from the server side in that javascript function call: `onChange="getcenter(<%=yourstateIDVariable%>,this.value);"`

Comment: it is working perfect now. i have just added - onChange="getcenter(<%=stateID%>,this.value)" in findcity.asp page. thank you for your suggestion